# How do I turn this search function into case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

As a newbie, I have been having problems converting this search function to being case insensitive. It is currently working as it is but it only shows the results if it matches its exact case like a search of "Item 1" will output "Item 1" but would not if it is "item 1".

```
function processorOfFormSearch(formObject){  
var result = "";
if(formObject.searchtext){    //***********Execute if form passes search text
  result = search(formObject.searchtext);
}
return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
var spreadsheetId   = globalVariables().asArray.spreadsheetId;
var dataRange        = globalVariables().asArray.dataRange;
var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
var ar = [];

data.forEach(function(f) {
   if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
   ar.push(f);
   }
 });
return ar;
}
```

Comment: Convert both your search text and the text being searched to lowercase (or uppercase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new RegExp` with your `searchText` as the first parameter, and `'i'` as the second parameter, indicating ***case insensitive***. Then run your data values through it using `.test()` I know your example uses `indexOf` so you may have to make some adjustments, but the general idea is there.

### Sample Script

```js
const data = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'item 3', 'item 1', 'ITEM 1']
const searchText = 'Item 1'
let arr = []

const validateText = (query) => {
  let regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i')
  return regex.test(query)

}

data.forEach(d => {
  if (validateText(d)) {
    arr.push(d);
  }
})

console.log('results of arr',
  arr
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I have been searching for a while and this has been the most simplest and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this

```
function search(searchtext) {
  var spreadsheetId = globalVariables().asArray.spreadsheetId;
  var dataRange = globalVariables().asArray.dataRange;
  var orow = dataRange.getRow();
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRange).values;
  var ar = [];
  dataRange.createTextFinder(searchtext).matchCase(false).findAll().forEach(r => {
    ar.push(data[r.getRow() - orow]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they strings? Why not use a filter that matches the data set to lowercase and the search string set to lowercase?

```
const result = data.filter((data) => {
  return data.toLowerCase() === searchtext.toLowerCase();
});
```